# Adding button that continually adds overlays to Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I've created this map for my upcoming road trip and I'm trying to figure out how (or if it's possible) to create a button that continually adds overlays to the leaflet map (i.e. cycling through the different days/steps in my road trip).

Example:

[image]
[image]

This is the code I am working with (each step has a variable like "d1a" (Day 1/Step A):

```
var route = {"color": "#FF0000", "fillOpacity": 1, "fillColor": "#FF0000", "weight": 3, "opacity": 1};

var myIcon = L.icon({iconUrl: 'circle.png', iconSize: [8, 8]})

var d1a = L.geoJSON(day01a, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature, style: route, pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {return L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon})}});
var d1a = L.geoJSON(day01b, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature, style: route, pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {return L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon})}});

var satellite   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.satellite', attribution: mbAttr}),

street  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.streets', attribution: mbAttr});

var map = L.map('map', {center: [37.792965, -111.485824], zoom: 5, layers: [street, d1a, d1b]});

var baseLayers = {"Satellite": satellite, "Street": street};
var overlays = {"Step 01": d1a, "Step 02": d1b};;

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: small typo - when you mean to declare d1b it says d1a

Answer (score 3):

First put your daily routes into an array and keep track of the steps:

```
var routes = [d1a, d1b, d2a, d3a];
var step = 0;
```

When you create the map object, just include the first day in the layers:

```
var map = L.map('map', {center: [37.792965, -111.485824], zoom: 5, layers: [street, routes[0]]});
```

Then make a function that cycles the list, adding the layers from the map:

```
function cycle() {
    step += 1;     
    if (step <= routes.length) {
        // map.removeLayer(routes[step-1]); if you want the previous segment to disappear
        map.addLayer(routes[step]); 
    }
}
```

Have your button run `cycle()` and the layers should get sequentially added.